# Unknown trigger and search type; agent may be corrupt - Lotus Notes / Domino Agent Error

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, agent

I have a scheduled Lotus Notes / Domino agent (8.5.3) which just will not run. It works fine when run manually. The agent log gives the error "Unknown trigger and search type; agent may be corrupt". The agent is signed with the Server ID. Security level = "Allow restricted operations". What else can I check?

Comment: what are the agent's trigger settings? what does the agent do? more details are required to answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error  "Unknown trigger and search type" can occur if you have an agent set to activate one way, and you attempt to force it to run another way.

For example you have set it to run on incoming documents, but attempt to run it from the server console.

You need to check the following settings in the agent preferences, to see if they are correct:

[image: Runtime preferences]

More details on these settings here.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/agt_trigger_agent_on_event_t.html

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/agt_trigger_agent_on_schedule_t.html

If it is a case of corruption, you can try modifying these settings and save the agent. Alternatively create a new agent, copy over the code and replace it with the previous agent.